# Java smooth scrolling (Game)

Tags: java, 2d

Ok, so I have a game I just started and I am kind of stuck on the smooth scrolling. I have the basic scrolling part done but my background (Grid) only moves by intervals of 50.

```
for (int x = (getPlayerX() / getTileSize()) - 6; x < (getPlayerX() / getTileSize()) + 9; x++)
{
    for (int y = (getPlayerY() / getTileSize()) - 5; y < (getPlayerY() / getTileSize()) + 8; y++)
    {

        int xPos = ((x - (getPlayerX() / tileSize)) + (getScreenX() / tileSize) - 1) * tileSize;
        int yPos = ((y - (getPlayerY() / tileSize)) + (getScreenY() / tileSize) - 1) * tileSize;
        if (x > 0 && x < mapX && y > 0 && y < mapY)
        {
            if (getTiles()[x][y].tileID == 0)
            {
                g.drawRect(xPos, yPos, tileSize, tileSize);
            }

            if (getTiles()[x][y].tileID == 1)
            {
                g.fillRect(xPos, yPos, tileSize + 1, tileSize + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry about the subtraction and addition in the for loops, I have them set up so it will display from 1 to whatever instead of 0 to whatever - 1.

So basically I want to redraw the grid every pixel I move, instead of every 50. Put I dont want to iterate over every pixel on the screen

Comment: Draw the background to a backing buffer and render the backing buffer by moving it as you need, the render will be faster

Comment: Trying to make a moving long level, right?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by 'long level' but it moves on the x and y axis.

To MadProgrammer: Let me explain the process. It goes through every tile that is 6 tiles to the left, 9 to the right, 5 to the top, and 8 to the bottom, a tile is 50px, so it can only draw them every 50xp... I need to get around that. I dont think a backing buffer will work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, at first you are confusing with the background and the grid. A grid is a way to check collisions and a spatial partitioning algorithm that never moves. A background is an image which is drawn behind every entity in your game in every level.

What you are trying to do is make the level scroll, as per what I understand. To do so, we create a class called `View` also called as a `Camera` which draws the background and the visible entities by centering the entity which is controlled by the player.

And to center an entity and draw the map, I use these classes. Hope you understand that I wrote them in C#.

- [Map](https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-cs/source/browse/MapEngine/Map.cs)
- [MapInfo](https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-cs/source/browse/MapEngine/MapInfo.cs)
- [MapLayer](https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-cs/source/browse/MapEngine/MapLayer.cs)
- [MapLoader](https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-cs/source/browse/MapEngine/MapLoader.cs)
- [MapManager](https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-cs/source/browse/MapEngine/MapManager.cs)
- [MapView](https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-cs/source/browse/MapEngine/MapView.cs)

And here is my implementation of [Grid](https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-cs/source/browse/Collision/Grid.cs). I have the java versions of the same classes [here](https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-java/source/browse/src/com/gej/map/) but I haven't implemented the Grid class in java.

You can read my tutorial [`Using Grids For Collisions`](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/using-grids-for-collisions/29244/view.html) for more info on how it works. Hope it helps.